# Simple function to find all built-in exceptions works when run directly, but fails when used as imported module, giving no traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a function that is supposed to generate a tuple of all built-in exceptions, (for use in the `except (Exception1, Exception2, etc...) as error:` form) and when I run it normally, it works just fine.

```
def get_exceptions():

    exceptionList = []

    for item in dir(__builtins__):
        if item.find('Error') != -1:
            exec('exceptionList.append({})'.format(item))

    return tuple(exceptionList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_exceptions())
```

and when run:

```
(<class 'ArithmeticError'>, <class 'AssertionError'>, <class 'AttributeError'>, <class 'BlockingIOError'>, <class 'BrokenPipeError'>, <class 'BufferError'>, <class 'ChildProcessError'>, <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>, <class 'ConnectionError'>, <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, <class 'ConnectionResetError'>, <class 'EOFError'>, <class 'OSError'>, <class 'FileExistsError'>, <class 'FileNotFoundError'>, <class 'FloatingPointError'>, <class 'OSError'>, <class 'ImportError'>, <class 'IndentationError'>, <class 'IndexError'>, <class 'InterruptedError'>, <class 'IsADirectoryError'>, <class 'KeyError'>, <class 'LookupError'>, <class 'MemoryError'>, <class 'NameError'>, <class 'NotADirectoryError'>, <class 'NotImplementedError'>, <class 'OSError'>, <class 'OverflowError'>, <class 'PermissionError'>, <class 'ProcessLookupError'>, <class 'ReferenceError'>, <class 'RuntimeError'>, <class 'SyntaxError'>, <class 'SystemError'>, <class 'TabError'>, <class 'TimeoutError'>, <class 'TypeError'>, <class 'UnboundLocalError'>, <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>, <class 'UnicodeError'>, <class 'UnicodeTranslateError'>, <class 'ValueError'>, <class 'OSError'>, <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>)
```

which is just as I wanted.
however, at the following, through the shell,

```
>>> import list_exceptions
>>> list_exceptions.get_exceptions()
()
```

nothing happens.

even in a file:

```
import list_exceptions
print(list_exceptions.get_exceptions())
```

i get:

```
()
```

this seems very strange. any help would be great!
by the way, I looked at these, they weren't really related to what I had in mind.
[import fails when running python as script, but not in iPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548587/import-fails-when-running-python-as-script-but-not-in-ipython)
http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

if you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: I am using the `exec` function so it adds the actual exception, not the string.

Comment: You can use `getattr(__builtins__, item)` to similar effect

Comment: Ok, so what would that look like? I have never used `getattr` before.

Comment: In a terminal, ```item.find('Error') != -1``` is always false.  Don't know why (yet), but that is what is happening.

Comment: ya, it is strange, I am on windows, and whenever I import it, in an IDE, or from any command line, it never works. when I run it by double clicking, or by running from cmd or powershell, it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your approach is that you are relying on two things you shouldn't rely on. The first is `dir`, the behavior of which should *not be relied on* because it exists mostly to aid debugging in the interactive shell. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its
>   best to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not
>   necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a
>   custom `__getattr__()`.
>
> ...
>
> **Note** Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of
>   names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently
>   defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across
>   releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list
>   when the argument is a class.

Furthermore, you use the `__builtins__` variable, which *is an implementation detail* Again, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/builtins.html):

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__`
>   made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is
>   normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__`
>   attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used
>   by alternate implementations of Python.

Essentially, you are relying on two unreliable things. Note, what is *actually happening* in your case is that when you run the module directly, it returns the actual `builtins` module, however, when the module is imported, `__builtins__` contains the "value of this module's `__dict__`". A few debugging prints could have illuminated this:

```
# builtinstest.py
def get_exceptions():

    print(type(__builtins__))
    print(dir(__builtins__))
```

And from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import builtinstest
>>> builtinstest.get_exceptions()
<class 'dict'>
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

So when you call `dir` on a `dict` object, it simply returns the attributes introspectable from the dict-object, e.g. `copy`, `fromkeys`, `get`, `items` and all the other `dict` methods. The solution is to use the `builtins` module and don't use `dir`, use `vars` (which just returns the `__dict__` attribute), since you want the attributes of the module object.

Finally, your approach with `exec` is not good. If you want to do this sanely, check if it is a subclass of `BaseException`, which is the parent class of all built-in exceptions, so from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException):

> exception `BaseException`
>
> The base class for all built-in exceptions. It is not meant to be 
>      directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use `Exception`).

So something like:

```
import builtins
def get_exceptions_sanely():
    exception_list = []
    for obj in  vars(builtins).values():
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, BaseException):
            exception_list.append(obj)
    return tuple(exception_list)
```

Does what you are trying to accomplish. Note, this iterates over the *values* directly, so you don't end up using something like `eval` or `exec`, which is an abuse in this case. Note, this catches *every* built-in exception, things like warnings, (e.g. `BytesWarning`) and more esoteric things like `SystemExit`.

#### Finally

Just because you *can* do this, doesn't mean you *should*. Your stated purpose is:

> I have a function that is supposed to generate a tuple of all built-in
>   exceptions, (for use in the `except (Exception1, Exception2, etc...)
>   as error:` form)

Well, you could just use `except BaseException as error` instead of going through the rigamarole of finding those exceptions in the first place (indeed, `except <something>` essentially checks if `<something>` `issubclass` of whatever error is being raised. And fundamentally, there is *rarely* ever any good reason to have such a broad `except` clause. You should always try to catch as narrow an exception as possible.

Comment: wow. I am amazed at the detail of this answer. I just learned a lot about things I had no idea about, and all sorts of cool things. by the way, I wanted to be able to catch all exceptions and give them a name, because I am making a game and if an exception is thrown, I want to put the exception in a message box and have it be reported back to me. that is why I didnt just use `except:` because you cant do `except as thingy.` thank you!

Comment: @Michael yeah, generally, you do `except Exception as e`, sometimes you do that just to report something, maybe do cleanup, then exit. Again, you probably *should not* be letting exceptions pass silently, of course, it isn't always possible, but in the case of a game, and built-in exceptions, you should be handling them or fixing the cause

Comment: of course. I know putting just an `except:` default anywhere is a terrible idea   because the whole idea of the traceback system is to crash your program when something unexpected happens. if an exception happens in my game, it will open a message box, try and save progress, and call `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, and seems to be the common technique for getting at the builtins module.

```
def get_exceptions():

    exceptionList = []

    for k in __builtins__.keys():
        if k.find('Error') != -1:
            exec('exceptionList.append({})'.format(k))

    return tuple(exceptionList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_exceptions())
```

Comment: i got:  
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\list_exceptions.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(get_exceptions())
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\list_exceptions.py", line 5, in get_exceptions
    for k in __builtins__.keys():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keys'
>>> `

Comment: I used:
`import builtins
    keys = builtins.__dict__` and that worked.